# How can i fix divisible by 0 error in this code

Tags: python

This code is throwing divisible by 0 error

```
 for key in results_dic:

    # match (if dog then breed match)
    if results_dic[key][2] == 1:

        # isa dog (pet label) & breed match
        if results_dic[key][3] == 1:
            n_pet_dog += 1

            # isa dog (classifier label) & breed match
            if results_dic[key][4] == 1:
                n_class_cdog += 1
                n_match_breed += 1

        # NOT dog (pet_label)
        else:

            # NOT dog (classifier label)
            if results_dic[key][4] == 0:
                n_class_cnotd += 1

    # NOT - match (not a breed match if a dog)
    else:

        # NOT - match
        # isa dog (pet label) 
        if results_dic[key][3] == 1:
            n_pet_dog += 1

            # isa dog (classifier label)
            if results_dic[key][4] == 1:
                n_class_cdog += 1

        # NOT dog (pet_label)
        else:

            # NOT dog (classifier label)
            if results_dic[key][4] == 0:
                n_class_cnotd += 1


# calculates statistics based upon counters from above
n_pet_notd = n_images - n_pet_dog
pct_corr_dog = ( n_class_cdog / n_pet_dog )*100
pct_corr_notdog = ( n_class_cnotd / n_pet_notd )*100
pct_corr_breed = ( n_match_breed / n_pet_dog )*100
```

Even if i use if-else statement it throws the same error should i use exception statement and how can i use it in this situation i have been told that this because of an indent error but i checked it and it should have no problem

Comment: Assuming `n_pet_dog` and `n_pet_notd ` are integers,  I would recommend changing denominator to `max(n_pet_notd, 1)` and `max(n_pet_dog, 1)` so that you can avoid using the min value 0 there and instead fallback to 1 as minimum

Comment: @akazuko How to do that ?

Comment: like I mentioned above. Example: change `pct_corr_dog = ( n_class_cdog / n_pet_dog )*100` to `pct_corr_dog = ( n_class_cdog / max(n_pet_dog,1) )*100`

Comment: thank you this solved my error

Comment: cool, upvote the answer and mark it as accepted then? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n_pet_dog` and `n_pet_notd` are integers, I would recommend changing denominator to `max(n_pet_notd, 1)` and `max(n_pet_dog, 1)` so that you can avoid using the min value `0` there and instead fallback to `1` as minimum. Example: change

```
pct_corr_dog = ( n_class_cdog / n_pet_dog )*100
```

to

```
pct_corr_dog = ( n_class_cdog / max(n_pet_dog,1) )*100
```

Answer (score 0):

You fix division-by-zero by not dividing by zero.

In `( n_class_cdog / n_pet_dog )` it is possible that n_pet_dog is zero.  This is more-or-less inevitable; there may be no pet dogs.

In this case trying to determine the percentage of things that are pet dogs is meaningless, so you should (a) not execute this statement, and (b) decide what you want your code to do in the event there are no pet dogs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator for a clean code.

```
pct_corr_dog = (n_class_cdog/n_pet_dog)*100 if (n_pet_dog != 0) else #what to do otherwise
```